# eclipse c compiled library

Tags: c, eclipse, libraries

I am using Eclipse to create a C project. I had some C source code that I'm using for a library, which I compiled successfully separately. I now want to use that library in my Eclipse project. I added a folder of the library to my project, but when I compile the project in Eclipse, I am getting a large number of errors coming from the library. How do I solve this?

Many of the errors are variables "undefined"

Comment: you need to refer to CDT and how to set build targets http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdvhelp/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_c_build_over.htm

Comment: @user1190650 What is the errors?Edit your errors with you post ..

Comment: What do I do with the build target?